# Catalog of Features. Feature extraction from images for SVM

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, svm

I'm looking for reliable features for classification of cell types in microscope images. I wonder what is the best approach.

1) I've tried the approach described by Pontil & Verii - using each pixel of normalized images as a feature. It is easy to implement, but the results are not fully satisfactory. And another problem is - the classification is done with some kind of statistic magic and I can't understand why some results are bad.

2) I've tried to extract high level features such as peaks, holes. My implementation is slow, but the advantage is I understand why one cell is identified as such and another not, as you can visualize these features in test images.

3) Recently I've found in an article such features:

> angular second-order, 
>   distance, contrast, entropy, anti-difference distance, relevant, mean
>   of sum, mean of difference, entropy of sum, entropy of difference,
>   variance, variance of sum, variance of difference.

I wonder whether there are some standard libraries for the extraction of these features (preferably in C/C++) ?
Is there a catalogue of feature-types with pros/cons, use-case description, etc?

Thank you for any suggestion in advance!

Comment: `the classification is done with some kind of statistic magic` does this mean you dislike SVM or are you referring to something else?

Comment: @MarcClaesen: Dislike SVM? Not at all! I'm referring to the set of features. In my 2nd approach I am able to evaluate each feature independently. Ones having small std. deviation over all training instances will improve the recognition (as my intuition tells me). I've built a tool which evaluates pluggable, parametrized features. So I can semi-automatically determine the best parameters for a particular feature (e.g Peak height for Peak-feature). In the 1st approach, the features are very low-level and have very big std. deviation. So the contribution of each feature to the result is obscure.

Comment: Can you please upload some example images?

Comment: @GilLevi: I would expect, there is a catalog, which is not dependent to resolution, intensity variation, noise, etc. I think my particular images are not relevant. However, if you are interested, they look similar to those in the article: http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/24/1/94.full.pdf

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz, it seems you're into Image Processing - could you assist us open this dedicated group: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision/72084 Just vote to questions with less than 10 up votes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found what I've searched for and would like to share:
https://sites.google.com/site/cvonlinewiki/home/geometric-feature-extraction-methods

The list looks pretty mature and complete.

**EDIT**
Another good article for features in biological cells is:

[A feature set for cytometry on digitized
microscopic images](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/acp/2003/548678.pdf)

A good description of shape features:
http://www.math.uci.edu/icamp/summer/research_11/park/shape_descriptors_survey.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [this article](http://www.cb.uu.se/~carolina/web_ims/Lindblad_Cytometry_2004.pdf) by Lindblad et al, published in the scientific journal Cytometry. It covers some aspects of feature extraction and classification of cells. It does not utilize any standard libraries for feature extraction/classification, but it contains some information on how to build a classifier based on general features.

This might not solve your problem completely, but I hope it might help you move towards a better solution.

Comment: +1: Thanks!!! Googling for Lindblad brought me a couple of interesting articles. (e.g. http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/24/1/94.full.pdf)

Comment: Since none of the answers was what I was looking for, I would like to give you the  bounty. Some of the articles by Lindblad gave me really good ideas, how to procede. I wont however select your answer as it does not answers the question. Hope it is ok.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty! I did not expect my answer to get accepted since it didn't answer the question. I just hoped it would help and I'm glad it did.

Answer (score 1):

You should try Gabor feature extraction technique as it is supposed to extract features very similar to human visual cortical cells...by setting filters at different orientation and scale and then extracting features from each set-up .
you can Start learning from [Wikipedea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter)

Comment: +1: Thanks, looks interesting. This is what I am looking for - how to detect features, which as a human being would detect it. However, it is only a technique for feature extraction, not a catalogue.

Comment: You are welcome....yeah there is not a catalogue for features...but may be learning it deeply could lead to some understanding yourself

Answer (score 0):

I think that the **[Insight Segmentation and Registration Toolkit (ITK)](http://www.itk.org/)** or **[Visualization Toolkit (VTK)](http://www.vtk.org/)** would work well.

Some other options (that might not necessarily include all the features you want) are

- http://opencv.org/
- http://gdal.org/
- http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=VIPS
- http://www.xdp.it/cximage.htm

Comment: I am not looking for an image processing toolkit but for a toolkit independant description of features. A catalogue where with a named features, description of use-cases and may be references to a particular implementations.

Comment: it seems you're into Image Processing - could you assist us open this dedicated group: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision/72084 Just vote to questions with less than 10 up votes. Thanks.